# Web Service ArrayOfString

Tags: c#, web-services, arrayofstring

How to keep the object returned by the web service as `ArrayOfString` ?

Contextualizing:

I'm giving maintenance in an application that consumes a Web Service, and a certain object would be a `List<string>` was being returned as `ArrayOfString` . Where did the Update in reference the WebService , the return moved to `string[]` what you can do to keep as `ArrayOfString` ?

It is returning as well :

```
private string[] motivoInterrupcaoField;
```

When should return this:

> [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
>               private Atendimento.wsAtendimento.ArrayOfString MotivoInterrupcaoField;

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

If your service method returns `List<string>` you will see this return value translated to an object of type `ArrayOfString` in the proxy. When your service method is designed to return `string[]` you will find `string[]` in the proxy.

If the return values for service methods have changed, client side, that implies the service contract has changed. If you don't control the contract there's not much you can do, except implement your own ArrayOfString class for use on the client (which, imo, shouldn't be all that hard to do).

Not a bad solution I think because it does imply that you simply adapt the client to the changes made to the service contract.